# How to completely detach/destroy MutationObserver (Possible Memory Leak)

Tags: javascript, events, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, mutation-observers

So I have an element (let's call this "List") that I watch for changes (attr and childList add/remove) using **MutationObserver**. This element has a "***toggle***" switch which I'm using to enable/disabled element interaction and observation.

The toggle element is associated with observer.disconnect() which I use to disconnect the observer, just as I don't want further observations when it is toggled "**OFF**".

Now *the issue starts when I want to interact and "observe" this element again*. As I'm watching the logs, it seems that after reconnecting (observer.connect(...)). Previous mutations are still kept in memory.

I need to properly detach this observer as I'm also sending POST request to a mongodb server. With this issue, it causes some sort of bloats to my mutation list AND the kind of pollutes my POST request with more unnecessary HTTP requests. It's not included in this post but just mentioning for context.

---

Moving on the actual code, please see the logs and a simplified code structure of my app:

**HTML**

```
<div class="list" data-observe="false"> <!-- eventListener attached here, e.g, to ".list" -->
    <div class="list-header">
        <div class="list-toggle-wrap">
            <button class="toggle-btn">Toggle</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-content">
        <!-- observed elements here... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
const watch = e => {
    if (e.target.matches('.toggle-btn')) {

        const list = e.target.closest('.list')
        const config = {
            attributeFilter: ['value', 'class'],
            attributeOldValue: true,
            childList: true,
            subtree: true,
        }

        const rng = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
        const randomHash = () => crypto.randomBytes(6).toString('hex')

        // logging random strings to observe if instance is the same
        console.log(randomHash())

        const callback = mutations => {

            // just logging if mutations are being detected
            console.log(`mutation detected: ${rng}`)

            mutations.forEach(mutation => {
                 // handle mutations
            }
        }

        const observer = new MutationObserver(callback)

        if (list.dataset.observe === 'true') {
            // if observing
            console.log('Observer Disconnected.')
            list.removeEventListener('click', watch)
            observer.disconnect()
            list.dataset.observe = 'false'

        } else if (list.dataset.observe === 'false') {
            // if not observing
            console.log('Observer Connected.')
            list.dataset.observe = 'true'
            observer.observe(list, config)
        }
    }
}

const list = document.querySelector('.list')
list.addEventListener('click', watch)
```

**console.log**

```
/* I'm generating these by clicking toggle ON and OFF without mutating
 * anything else
 * 
 * Also do note that I'm filtering uneeded mutations on my callback so
 * it doesn't show/log here, figured I want to mention that since you
 * may ask if this is just some of the actual mutation happening,
 * which is actually not the case
 */

e520c5769d34           list.controller.js:250:12
Observer Connected...  list.controller.js:462:20
mutation detected: 44  list.controller.js:254:16
21cd886b5760           list.controller.js:250:12
Observer Disconnected. list.controller.js:428:20
mutation detected: 44  list.controller.js:254:16
5781b586160c           list.controller.js:250:12
Observer Connected...  list.controller.js:462:20
mutation detected: 44  list.controller.js:254:16
mutation detected: 72  list.controller.js:254:16
29c47a6f6ece           list.controller.js:250:12
Observer Disconnected. list.controller.js:428:20
mutation detected: 44  list.controller.js:254:16
mutation detected: 72  list.controller.js:254:16
797a9dfa19b2           list.controller.js:250:12
Observer Connected...  list.controller.js:462:20
mutation detected: 44  list.controller.js:254:16
mutation detected: 72  list.controller.js:254:16
mutation detected: 52  list.controller.js:254:16
b51b16721df9           list.controller.js:250:12
Observer Disconnected. list.controller.js:428:20
mutation detected: 44  list.controller.js:254:16
mutation detected: 72  list.controller.js:254:16
mutation detected: 52  list.controller.js:254:16
145ba03997a5           list.controller.js:250:12
Observer Connected...  list.controller.js:462:20
mutation detected: 44  list.controller.js:254:16
mutation detected: 72  list.controller.js:254:16
mutation detected: 52  list.controller.js:254:16
mutation detected: 15  list.controller.js:254:16
8acb6fabd173           list.controller.js:250:12
Observer Disconnected. list.controller.js:428:20
mutation detected: 44  list.controller.js:254:16
mutation detected: 72  list.controller.js:254:16
mutation detected: 52  list.controller.js:254:16
mutation detected: 15  list.controller.js:254:16
1a9f20e41cb5           list.controller.js:250:12
Observer Connected...  list.controller.js:462:20
mutation detected: 44  list.controller.js:254:16
mutation detected: 72  list.controller.js:254:16
mutation detected: 52  list.controller.js:254:16
mutation detected: 15  list.controller.js:254:16
mutation detected: 55  list.controller.js:254:16
f4393ece6540           list.controller.js:250:12
Observer Disconnected. list.controller.js:428:20
mutation detected: 44  list.controller.js:254:16
mutation detected: 72  list.controller.js:254:16
mutation detected: 52  list.controller.js:254:16
mutation detected: 15  list.controller.js:254:16
mutation detected: 55  list.controller.js:254:16
762116b899da           list.controller.js:250:12
Observer Connected...  list.controller.js:462:20
mutation detected: 44  list.controller.js:254:16
mutation detected: 72  list.controller.js:254:16
mutation detected: 52  list.controller.js:254:16
mutation detected: 15  list.controller.js:254:16
mutation detected: 55  list.controller.js:254:16
mutation detected: 6   list.controller.js:254:16
and so on...
```

As you can see, the log shows it is a different event instance every time BUT for some reason, old mutation references are kept even though I have disconnected from the observer already.

---

Things I've tried so far.

- removedEventListener and re-added on the `'.list'` element on each
  disconnect()
- `null`'ed and `deleted` the observer and instantiated
  new Observer on each disconnect()
- attached listener to toggle and
  `toggle.parentNode.removeChild(toggle)` to remove the element from
  the DOM, hopefully removing references to it as well (no luck here), then re-creating a new DOM toggle after.

Would really appreciate if anyone could figure out how this is the case and how can I garbage collect/completely dereference this observer so when I toggle **ON**, it will be as if instatiated a new Observer without those previous records being retained in memory.

Edit: log connect/disconnect message

Comment: Sounds like you might need `observer.takeRecords()` to empty the queue after disconnecting.

Comment: Yeah, forgot to mention but I've already tried this. `takeRecords()` just returns an empty array since I've mostly handled all the mutation on the first callback instance.

Comment: Oh, I see, you create a new instance of MutationObserver each run so *it'll never be the same* as the one you created previously, thus disconnecting it serves zero purpose. You need to declare just one `observer` outside of `watch()` scope and connect/disconnect it when needed.

Comment: Just did that. You are right, observer should only be instantiated once and it should be outside the watch callback as putting it inside will instantiate a new observer for every new event.